# Android display Splash-Screen while loading but getting black screen instead

Tags: android, themes, drawable, splash-screen

I'm trying suggestion #2 from this question:
[Android display Splash-Screen while loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473557/android-display-splash-screen-while-loading)

This is using a theme with a background drawable then loading MainActivity from Splash.java which uses said theme to display an image while MainActivity processes and loads.

I'm getting a black screen for several seconds then the main screen appears on first load.

Am I missing something?  Or is this working correctly?  If it's working correctly, how do I get an image to show instead of the black screen if possible?

@drawable/background_splash

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Fill the background with a solid color -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <item>

        <!-- Place your bitmap in the center -->
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

@styles

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<!-- Splash Screen theme -->
<style name="SplashTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.epicdecals.openslider">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/open_slider_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".Splash"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Splash.java

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
}
```

Comment: Where is your xml for splash screen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15832037/6478047 see this for reference

Comment: you are using `Splash extends Activity` , you have to use this `Splash extends AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: @Champandroid there isn't one on purpose according to the article.

Comment: @Ironman Done but did not change anything.

Comment: @Redman I tried adding setTheme(R.style.SplashTheme); in Splash, I'm getting animations now when it goes to the main screen but there is still a 10 second black screen until the main screen.

Comment: @Redman Got it! thanks for the link.  I had to add parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar" in the style tag.  Post an answer and I'll accept.  Thanks again!

Comment: glad it helped :)

Comment: Actually it only works in portrait, not landscape.  Any reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a parent in the style theme to get it working.  Thank you for the link in the comments Redman ^^^^.

EX:

```
<style name="SplashTheme"
    parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think Your Flash Screen is not load because are you not set any time of splash screen.
Try blow code:

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

private CountDownTimer timer = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    timer = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
               Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               finish();
        }
    };
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    timer.cancel();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    timer = null;
}
```

Comment: Cannot resolve constructor 'intent'
I really only want it to show while starting up (doing something while no screen is visible)  I was under the impression that it would show instead of the black screen I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

// This  is working for me. 
   // This is Splash.java

```
public class Splash extends ActionBarActivity
 {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

            Thread th = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                  // write your activity which you want to open

             Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                }
            }
        };
        th.start();
    }

}
```

// and this is my Splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/bk_client"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

      </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```